# Microsoft's code is not working in praxis

Tags: visual-c++

This code, under msvc 2022:

```
const char* chars = "XBECEDX";
for each (char c in chars)
{
    if (c == 'X') std::cout << 'A';
    else
        std::cout << c;
}
```

Ends with error E0125, E0065, E0029
Maybe output is: ABECEDA

Where is the Failure? Is it bad code or bad compiler or compiler setting or any Failure.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this as vector with lambda function. Here is example:

```
string s = "XBECEDX";
for_each(s.begin(), s.end(), [](char ch)
{ 
   if (c == 'X') std::cout << 'A';
   else std::cout << c;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    string chars = "XBECEDX";
    // char chars[] = "XBECEDX"; // will also work as an alternate to string

    for (char c : chars)
    {
        if (c == 'X') std::cout << 'A';
        else
            std::cout << c;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for Answer. Yes, You are right, but i will use for mass data input of structs. My Question-Code is only Example